# What exactly is bootstrap admin-template and how it is supposed to be used

Tags: javascript, templates, asp.net-mvc-4

So this is my second ASP.NET MVC 4 project. It's decided that for this one we will use [this template](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR) and it was said in a way that I felt really stupid for not knowing how exactly this template will help us and what exactly we gain by using it.

I'm used to using HTML/CSS for the UI combined with jQuery. Now it seems that instead of jQuery we will be using bootstrap which as far as I understand is just another JS library created from twitter, so if that's it then this part is clear. What I really need to clarify for myself is what exactly this theme is used for, what is offering, why one would want to use such a theme? From what I see in the live demo maybe it's just a stack of premade controls that you can use in the front end along with bootstrap.js and maybe I'm just confused because on the page is shown as much as possible just for presentational purposes. If that's right, still I wonder where I can find info for the current theme, the controls that it offers and the functionality that I get and not least - how to use it.

But still those are just my assumptions. What I really need is a clarification on what exactly is this theme for, what is the advantage using it, is there a good tutorials about how to use such themes in the context of ASP.NET MVC 3+.

Also any additional info about this theme and generally on using themes in ASP.NET MVC will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap is less of a javascript library and more of a CSS framework with some additional javascript widgets. There is nothing preventing you from using jQuery or some other javascript library of your choice (indeed, it may be required to get the functionality you need.)

The use case for Bootstrap is to get the product out the door without spending time worrying about how each control should look. It defines some standard styles for common elements/widgets and styles them to look good. It uses best practices and common sense to get a uniform look for everything.

There is absolutely nothing that is ASP.NET MVC specific about Bootstrap. It is pure front-end goodness, so it doesn't care in the slightest on how you render the HTML to start with. The entire purpose of Bootstrap is to bootstrap (get it?) your user interface.

Comment: I understand that a big part of this is the component styling but in the demo there are a lot of charts for example. Are they also just styled elements or they have logic attached to them. And if there's a business logic (it just seems more logical to me) where I can see for this exact template (or any other, but I'm interested in this one in particular) information about how those controllers work, what kind of data they need, how it should be formatted or this is not the idea behind such a template?

Comment: After looking at the main page (not the demo) and looking at the features, the charts are provided via the jQuery Flot charts plugin and a lot of other features are provided via other jQuery plugins. You would have to look at the individual plugin documentation to see how the data need to be provided. The Bootstrap theme just provides some standard styling to these widgets to make them look like the rest of the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Admin templates are design mock-ups for an existing website admin panel to make it look appealing and easy to operate.

While building a brand-new website, the tendency is to think more about the front-end part of the project. Still, even if you aren’t creating a site from scratch, but having a revamp of a current one, you should take care of the backend side as well. What you need is a top-notch and rich in features admin panel. Take notice, though, that the Bootstrap themes in this selection will fit only a website with an already existing dashboard.

The website administration part should be easy in use and pleasing to the eyes as well. This is why, there are plenty of HTML dashboard templates available online,  free and also premium. Basically, an admin dashboard template is a set of design elements for the admin panel interface. So, if you're looking for solid dashboard themes, you've come to the right place!

Most of the modern admin dashboard designs are based on the Bootstrap 3 framework. It is a convenient to use and easy to modify mobile-first framework. Besides, it comes packed with numerous widgets and extra components.

It also renders well on different screen sizes and resolutions, so your Bootstrap dashboard template will always look consistent and clean.

You can find [Bootstrap admin template](https://themeselection.com/item/category/bootstrap-admin-templates/) collections by searching out in Google, or else from blog posts such as [20+ Bootstrap Admin Template Open Source](https://themeselection.com/bootstrap-admin-template-open-source/)

I have used the Robust Lite - Free Bootstrap admin template from my project which has an MIT license and is available on GitHub: https://github.com/themeselection/sneat-html-admin-template-free
Demo: https://themeselection.com/item/sneat-free-bootstrap-html-admin-template/

There are a lot of marketplaces such as ThemeForest, WrapBootstrap & ThemeSelection to get premium admin templates also.

Hope this will help you to understand and kick start your next project with the admin template.